# Neat code to convert bool[] -> "1,0,0,1,1"

Tags: c#, arrays, string

How would you convert an array of booleans to a string like "1,0,0,1,1" - using as few lines of code as possible?
And I want to convert it to string so I have a new string "@10011#" and I will send it through the Serial Port.
So what is a short way to do in C#?

Comment: `string.Concat(bools.Select(x => x ? "1" : "0"))`?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried and show us what problems you've encountered.

Comment: `string s = "@" + string.Join(",", bools.Select(b => b?1:0)) + "#";`

Comment: `string.Join(',', bools.Select(Convert.ToInt32))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this

```
var toSerial = $@"@{string.Join(",", arrayOfBool.Select(b => b ? "1" : "0"))}#";
```

This is just one line of code, so fulfils the requirement of "as few lines of code as possibe" while still being verbose enough for readability. Anything shorter would be a better fit for [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Because of the `$@"@` readability I would suggest regular string concatenation `"@" + string.Join...`. I wonder if couldn't it be `$"@{string.Join...` instead.